# How to get Inventory Count with site collection level permission(Repeat Question, But to be clarifying the previous question)

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

The farm is administered by outside contractor company.  Right now we have two site collection and 300 sub sites under them to perform inventory count it needs at list member permission to the farm, is there any way to do inventory of these  site collection with out farm permission.

Is that possible to get an inventory count on site collection permission level with out farm level permission?

Comment: Hi, Could you please clarify what do you mean with the inventory count?

Comment: Thanks M. Qassas for responding. we are preparing for migration to number of sub sites lists / library and site owner and such,